# carga de datos en un combobox

Tags: java, sql

tengo una ventana en la cual tengo 2 comboboxes en el primero cargo los datos de una tabla llamada categoría donde el valor de cada ítem es el código que le doy a cada categoría en el segundo combobox quiero cargar los productos que tengan igual código en la columna categoría.

- en el primer combobox se puede tener el valor de nulo

estoy consultando el transact_sql y me dice que debo usar un inner join xq el código de la categoría sería un valor en común entre las tablas, estoy probando esto pero no me devuelve algún valor:

```
public List<Producto> SeleccionarProducto(String codigoCategoria) {
    Connection cnConexion=Database.getConexion();        
    PreparedStatement psproduct=null;
    ResultSet rproduct=null;
    List<Producto> listaProductos=new ArrayList<>();        
    try {
        String consulta="select codigo, producto from Producto where estado='A' and categoria='"+codigoCategoria+"' order by producto asc";            
        psproduct=cnConexion.prepareStatement(empleado);
        rproduct=psempleado.executeQuery();            
        while(rproduct.next()) {    
            Producto item=new Producto();
            item.setCod_producto(rproduct.getString("codigo"));
            item.setNombres(rproduct.getString("producto"));                
            listaProductos.add(item);
        }            
        psproduct.close();
        rproduct.close();            
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    finally {
        try {
            cnConexion.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }        
    return listaProductos;                
}
```

Me pueden ayudar en el correcto planteamiento de esto... se que estoy mal en el select aunque en físico si me funciona, es decir directamente probando la sentencia en el sql

Comment: El parámetro que recibe el método se llama *codigoCategoria* pero la variable que usas para montar el SQL se denomina *codCategoria*... ¿es un error al poner el código aquí o es que te has confundido de variable en el programa?

Comment: En todo caso, deberías intentar hacer el problema más pequeño... si es un problema de que no lees los datos de SQL, poner la información sobre el ComboBox no es relevante (porque no da igual para qué quieras usar los datos, el problema es que no los lees). Si lees los datos pero tienes problemas para representarlos en ComboBox, que los datos te vengan de SQL o no es irrelevante. Cuanto mejor definas el problema, más probabilidades habrá de que obtengas una solución.

Comment: SJuan 76 le pongo ese nombre a la variable porque es un método que luego le voy a llamar en el principal.......y si esta mal porque en el select debe ser codigoCategoria; la tabla Producto tiene las columnas: id, categoria, producto. La tabla donde tengo las categorías solo tienen el codigo de la categoría y la descripción, en el primer combobox que mencione cargo las descripciones y a cada descripción le di su respectivo valor, pero en el select no me muestra algún ítem

Comment: la cosa es que ese combobox actua como filtro para ver los productos en el siguiente combobox; si se como leer tablas, ya lo he hecho con select * from tabla... sin ningún filtro.. que yo le pase a una función y eso es lo que quiero averiguar para poder realizar un método de busqueda con parámetro(s)